# Use ReactNative for UI but still use native API for other things

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I try to develop my app that only use ReactNative for UI but still use (in Android) Activity/Fragment/Service classes for business logic. Same thing for iOS, still use Controller, etc for business logic.

But when I search on Google, on Youtube, all tutorials I found only tells how to make app that has only UI thing, pure ReactNative code. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to only make UI with ReactNative but still keep using native API e.g. Activity/Fragment/Service (Android), Controller (iOS) in my mobile project?
2. If it is possible, how? Any good tutorials (both Android and iOS)?

Comment: i wrote two tutorials on this. check them out. one is setup and the other is passing info back to the native side. https://apptillery.info/development/basic-setup-add-react-native-existing-ios-project/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@talkol/performance-limitations-of-react-native-and-how-to-overcome-them-947630d7f440), I wouldn't recommend using native modules for EVERYTHING (Activity/Fragment/Service..)

> The performance bottleneck often occurs when we move from one realm (native or javascript) to the other. In order to architect performant React Native apps, we must keep passes over the bridge to a minimum.

If you are interested in knowing, [this is how bridging works](https://tadeuzagallo.com/blog/react-native-bridge/)

Is it possible to do what you want? Yes.
But if you are going to have the activities, services and business logic you might as well do it all in native.

Depending on your app necessities react-native will be suitable for you or not. If your app **depends highly** on hardware (bluetooth, accelerometer,etc), needs high frame rate performance (like a game) or **heavy interaction** with other apps (content provider) or device system (like alarm manager) then I wouldn't recommend using it. Otherwise, it is an amazing option.

Comment: Thanks, does it mean when using ReacNative it's better to write business logic also in jxe/javascript ? e.g. send request to backend, light calculation, etc.

Comment: Yes, you can do everything in javascript. For managing your bussiness logic I recommend you use a state managment library called Redux (you will find that is the most used for its simplicity to write test and other stuff). Before learning it you should first be comfortable with javascript and react (using setState). To send request to backend or do any asynchronous calls there are libraries that complement with Redux pretty well like Redux Thunk (althought you can do that without any library). But thats going way ahead.If you are just starting and need some orientation dont hesitate to mail me

Comment: Thanks! I will contact you. Yep, I think I need some orientation. :)